# How to send the data from android(Client) to PC(WampServer) without an internet connection?

Tags: android, wampserver

Am running a wamp server on my PC and i connected it to my android 2.2 device through WiFi.
    In my app there is a listview of options to be selected, if i select some options, the Server should display those options which are only selected.There will be no internet connection. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

If the android device and the PC are on the same wifi network or internally routable to each other by a LAN including that wifi, you can use ordinary TCP client/server methods to communicate between them.

Comment: I am in a Search of the Same thing. Please provide any demo if you have.